# Android socket throws UnknownHostException error

Tags: java, android, sockets

Why do I get this error...

> java.net.UnknownHostException: http://google.com

...when I do this in my Activity -> onCreate?

```
try {
   Socket socket = new Socket("http://google.com", 80);
} catch(Exception e) {
   Log.e(tag, e.toString());
   return;
}
```

And yes, I do have the Internet permission set in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This is being tested on a physical Nexus S phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `www.google.com`, without the `http://` part.

Answer (score 1):

Is it throwing an UnknownException or UnknownHostException?

UnknownHostException means there is a problem with the hostname lookup.  Try it without the "http://" and if that doesn't work, try it with the direct IP address.

Its not your app permissions that is failing, otherwise it would throw a SecurityException.

Answer (score 0):

Socket throws an
UnknownHostException - if the IP address of the host could not be determined.

Do you have Internet Access enabled? Try it with another host or with the IP and/or try restarting your phone.